# Swift Fatal Error index out of range while using searchbar in tableview

Tags: swift, tableview, searchbar

i try to load an json data with tableView and i wanna add search data using uiSearchBar, data is search well but when i try to hit 'x' button on the searchBar or when i try to backspace the input it crash...Any help guys? or should i change my search method? thanks for the help. I'm still new in swift so if theres a better method to search please let me know:)

```
  struct ProjectSumName: Decodable {
     let id : Int
      let name : String

enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case id = "id"
    case name = "name"
  }
}


 class ProjectSumController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var SearchBar: UISearchBar!
  @IBOutlet weak var ProjectSumTableView: UITableView!

  var projectSum = [ProjectSumName]()
  var filterProject : [ProjectSumName] = [ProjectSumName]()
  var isSearch : Bool = false

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    SearchBar.delegate = self

      Loading()
      let jsonUrl = "http://\(GlobalVariable.ip):7000/api/projectApi?UserId=\(GlobalVariable.UserIdProjectSum)"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrl) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do{
            let projectsum = try JSONDecoder().decode([ProjectSumName].self, from: data)
            self.projectSum = projectsum
            self.filterProject = projectsum
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                self.ProjectSumTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
  }
} 



   extension ProjectSumController : UISearchBarDelegate,  UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isSearch{
        return filterProject.count
    }else{
        return projectSum.count
    }
}
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let proc = projectSum[indexPath.row]
    let proc1 = filterProject[indexPath.row]
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? ProjectSumTableCell else {return UITableViewCell()}

    if isSearch{
        cell.NameLbl.text = proc1.name
    }else{
        cell.NameLbl.text = proc.name
    }
    return cell
}

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let sum = projectSum[indexPath.row]
    let sum1 = filterProject[indexPath.row]

    if isSearch{
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: sum1)
        let projectIDs = sum1.id
        GlobalVariable.ProjectId = String(projectIDs)
    }else{
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: sum)
        let projectID = sum.id
        GlobalVariable.ProjectId = String(projectID)
    }
}

 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchText.isEmpty{
            self.isSearch = false;
            self.ProjectSumTableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            self.filterProject = self.projectSum.filter({  (ProjectSumName) -> Bool in

                let tmp : NSString = NSString.init(string: ProjectSumName.name)
                let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)

                return range.location != NSNotFound && range.location == 0
            })
            if(self.filterProject.count == 0){
                self.isSearch = false;
            }else{
                self.isSearch = true;
            }
            self.ProjectSumTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

"Fatal error: Index out of range
2019-06-27 09:43:46.167472+0700 ImmobiTracker[806:30114] Fatal error: Index out of range"

that crash come up everything i try to clear my searchbar...so when i try to type the first time to search its filtering the data, but when i try to clear the search bar it pop crash

Comment: Unrelated but your way to filter the data is horrible. There is no reason at all to use `NSString`. This is the native way: `self.filterProject = self.projectSum.filter{$0.name.range(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two places** where you are getting this error.

1. in cellForRowAt:

   ```
   let proc = projectSum[indexPath.row]
   let proc1 = filterProject[indexPath.row]
   ```
2. didSelectRowAt

   ```
   let sum = projectSum[indexPath.row]
   let sum1 = filterProject[indexPath.row]
   ```

**Why**:

You are trying to get an element from filterProject without using `isSearch` i.e. filterPoject array is empty. When `isSearch` is `false` then the error occurs because you are trying to get the element from the empty array.

**How to Solve this**:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let sum: ProjectSumName
    if isSearch{
        sum = filterProject[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        sum = projectSum[indexPath.row]
    }
    GlobalVariable.ProjectId = String(sum.id)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: sum)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? ProjectSumTableCell else {return UITableViewCell()}

    let proc: ProjectSumName
    if isSearch{
        proc = filterProject[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        proc = projectSum[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.NameLbl.text = proc.name
    return cell
}
```

Comment: woww it works very well sir thank you very much for your help:)